# What all is different between the 4 worm types?

Tags: worms-revolution

According to the tutorial the Heavy worm is "strong" and the Scientist and Scout worms are "weak". However so far I haven't found out exactly what it means by that...they start with the same health and appear to take about the same damage from attacks. What does the "toughness" of the worms do for them? I also know there are some other effects like the Scout's speed and thin-ness and the Scientist's stronger turrets.

What are all the differences between the 4 worm types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good in-depth explanation at [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/665657-worms-revolution/faqs/65125), but here's a quick summary:

- ***Heavies*** do the most damage, but have the worst agility. Best used in easy to navigate maps, enclosed spaces or game modes where the worms cannot move.
- ***Soldiers*** are the balanced worms: standard agility, standard damage. Great all-rounders. Soldiers function identical to the stock worms from other games.
- ***Scientists*** are great for support- summoned items like bridges/sentries last twice as long. Sink holes have a larger radius if summoned by a scientist. Each time it is a scientists turn *(real turn, not select worm or a free select map)*, all your worms gain +5 health. However their damage and blast radius takes a hit (pardon the pun). Best used for games of attrition or defensive "darkside" teams
- ***Scouts*** have the worst damage and take the most knock-back, however their fast speed and jump height makes them extremely useful for setting off mines, collecting crates and navigating treacherous maps. Tunnels dug by scouts can only be used by other scouts (grenades still fit as well). They work best on maps with shorter turn times.